# how to set an ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Can we set an `ArrayList` containing `HashMap` into an `ArrayAdapter`?

I'm using:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> ad = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
```

but this gives me an error saying:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter>>(searchname, int, ArrayList>) is undefined

Comment: have a look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274952/android-array-adapter-with-arraylist-and-listview-not-updating-when-the-arraylis

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayAdapter` wants to know the type of the items *inside* the list, not the type of the list itself. Remove the enclosing `ArrayList<>` and it should work.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items =
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> ad =
        new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
```

Comment: It print all the Items intead specific values inside hashmap.

Comment: @PawanSoni nothing in this example code or anywhere in this question prints anything, not entirely sure what you mean. But if you want use such an `ArrayAdapter` with a `ListView` or something similar you have to write code that uses the `HashMap<String,String>` items in the list in a way that is useful to you, that won't happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link [Android Array Adapter with ArrayList and ListView not updating when the arraylist is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274952/android-array-adapter-with-arraylist-and-listview-not-updating-when-the-arraylis).

basically you need to add your ArrayList into the ArrayAdapter through the add method.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the type `HashMap<String,String>>` to a class. For example, if the keys of the hashmap are countries and the values are lenguages, you can make a class called "Country" with this two variables (country,language).
Then the AdapterClass have to extend the `ArrayAdapter<Country>`, in the getView method you can access both variables of each Country.